# What is the basic process for wrapping a Mobile Website (webapp) in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm looking for the most simple way to wrap a Mobile Website into a PhoneGap application to install on Android and iOs.  I've seen various tutorials but I've had minimal luck getting a very simple siuation to work.

- http://antonylees.blogspot.com/2013/02/launch-website-as-mobile-app-using.html
- https://zolmeister.com/2014/01/how-to-turn-webapp-into-native-android.html
- https://github.com/causecode/phonegap-wrap

Say I wanted to wrap Yahoo.com in a PhoneGap application what is the minimum work that is required?

From what I gather I would need

- A Splash Screen
- An `index.html`
- An application Icon
- A `config.xml`

My understanding is the general principal in the `index.html` would be to have a javascript script that runs and then "loads" yahoo.com for example.

Should this task be quite simple or is it more involved than it seems at first look?

I'd also like to use the Phonegap-build website if possible ( I Don't know if that needs special configuration)

**It is my understanding that Cordova PhoneGap apps ARE in fact allowed on the app store**

Comment: apple dont accept apps which is just a wrapped website

Comment: I believe this was recently changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get away with that - use cordova/phonegap, create one page, have that page redirect to a mobile site. Submit that app to some build service, like PhoneGap Build, and then attempt to get it passed on stores. However, there's a good/better/best way of implementing a better mobile application, and that's not it. This question might be closed because of it's opinionated nature. So, there's my two cents.